# Else statement still running when if statement is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

I have search functionality that allows you to search for cryptocurrencies and I'm trying to have it where if the param/coin that is searched doesn't match with the API's title of the coin or symbol, an alert box would pop up telling the user to try again.

The problem I'm having is that if the if statement is true and there's a match, the else statement/alert box pops up regardless. Here's my code within my axios request:

```
cryPrice(param){
    axios.get(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=0`)
        .then(res => {
            const cryptos = res.data;
            const price = []

            for(let title in cryptos){
                const cryptoTitle = cryptos[title].name.toUpperCase();
                const cryptoSymbol = cryptos[title].symbol.toUpperCase();

                if(cryptoTitle === param || cryptoSymbol === param){
                    price.push(cryptos[title].price_usd);       
                }else{
                    alert("Please try again");
                    break;
                }
            }
            this.setState({
                priceResults: price
            })
        })
    }
```

Comment: how many times is the loop executed before the alert happens? what does `cryptos` look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your code loops through every single item in the array, as soon as a non-matching item is encountered it alerts and breaks the loop

What you probably want is more like

```
cryPrice(param){
    axios.get(`https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=0`)
    .then(res => {
        const priceResults = res.data
            .filter(item => [item.name.toUpperCase(), item.symbol.toUpperCase()].includes(param))
            .map(item => item.price_usd);
        if (priceResults.length) {
            this.setState({priceResults});
        } else {
            alert("Please try again");
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You find a match on some of the elements but alert about every other, all of those that do not match param. You should probably only alert *after* the loop execution has stopped and iff there were no currencies matched.